# XSD double binding to BigDecimal

Tags: java, xsd

I have

```
<xsd:element name="amount" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

in my xsd schema element.

But unfortunately I can't change that. Based on this document, I generate a class in Java with
Apache CXF. How can I parse this, get generated value in BigDecimal.

Now I have

```
protected Double amount;
```

But I want something like this

```
protected BigDecimal amount;
```

But I cant change my xsd element with Double. I would also not like to do it globally, but only for selected fields. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bindings file that tells jaxb to convert `xsd:double` to BigDecimal

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
        <xjc:javaType adapter="utils.BigDecimalXmlAdapter" name="java.math.BigDecimal" xmlType="xs:double"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

and BigDecimalXmlAdapter is

```java
package utils;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BigDecimalXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal unmarshal(String s) throws Exception {
        return new BigDecimal(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(BigDecimal bigDecimal) throws Exception {
        return bigDecimal.toString();
    }
}
```